# Remover sinalização

Tags: novo-recurso, sinalização

Admito que analisei mal a resposta dessa pergunta ([Problema em código Python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/368008/problema-em-c%C3%B3digo-python)) que apesar de ser pequena acredito que explicou bem qual foi o motivo do problema e orientou como corrigir. Acabei sinalizando ela como *baixa qualidade*.

Quando votamos para fechar, existe a possibilidade de retirar voto, mas e quando sinalizamos errado? Será que não teria uma forma de retirar a sinalização? Se não tem como não seria interessante ter esse recurso?